# Transformar un componente de clase en uno funcional

Tags: reactjs, programación-funcional, sortable

Tengo este componente de clase y necesito aplicar este codigo en un componente funcional, no se bien como convertir el estado usando useState.
Mi pregunta es si tengo que generar dos estados o en uno solo puedo pasar el objeto y el array vacio. Como quedaría el estado...

Ya que necesito agregar un array vacio para mover los elementos a ese nuevo array y aqui por lo que veo esta todo en un solo estado, tanto los datos como el array vacio. Como puedo transformar eso a un componente funcional

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { ReactSortable } from "react-sortablejs";

export default class List2 extends Component {
    state = {
        list: [
            { id: "1", name: "shrek" },
            { id: "2", name: "Nelson" },
            { id: "3", name: "Prueba" }
        ],
        list2: []
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div class="container">
                <div className="row align-items-start ">
                    <div className="col bg-success">
                    <h6 className="text-center">lista 1</h6>

                    <ReactSortable
                            list={this.state.list}
                            setList={newState => this.setState({ list: newState })}
                            group="shared-group-name"
                        >
                            {this.state.list.map(item => (
                                <div key={item.id}>
                                    <div className="card  m-3 cursor-draggable" >
                                        <div className="card-body">
                                            {item.name}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </ReactSortable>

                     </div>


                    <div class="col bg-danger">
                        <h6 className="text-center">lista 2</h6>

                        <ReactSortable
                            list={this.state.list2}
                            setList={newState => this.setState({ list2: newState })}
                            group="shared-group-name"
                        >
                            {this.state.list2.map(item => (
                                <div key={item.id}>
                                    <div className="card m-3 cursor-draggable" >
                                        <div className="card-body ">
                                            {item.name}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </ReactSortable>

                    </div>
                    <div className="col mt-3">
                        <h6>Puedas intercambiar datos entre la lista 1 y 2</h6>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta en un solo estado dado que `react` como `componente` solo soporta un estado, el cual debe ser un `objeto` en el cuál almacenas toda la información.  En `react` como `functions` al ser `hooks` pueden estar separados, por lo que puedes hacer sin problemas.

```
const [list1, setList1] = useState([
    { id: "1", name: "shrek" },
    { id: "2", name: "Nelson" },
    { id: "3", name: "Prueba" }
]);
const [list2, setList2] = useState([]);
```

Comment: Gracias, exactamente eso queria saber si se podia hacer... Ya me salio lo que queria.